# "Calling identity is not authorized" when calling resetPasswordWithToken

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an Android APP that uses [Device administration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin) to change the phone's password.

After properly adding it as an admin app, other DPM functions work fine (such as `dpm.lockNow()`), but when I try to change the password with the following code:

```java
dpm.setResetPasswordToken(mDeviceAdminSample, token);
dpm.resetPasswordWithToken(mDeviceAdminSample, "4567", token, 0);
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized
    at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
```

I registered the needed policy, so I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        ...
        <reset-password/>
        ...
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: Oh, well, maybe because of this https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation

Comment: This also happens when doing this dpm.setUninstallBlocked()

Answer (score 0):

Some device manager policies no longer work, I'm also creating an app and I see that only force-lock works, I wonder if there is a way to skip that SecurityException

Comment: From what I searched so far, there's no solution. I posted a comment with a link and it looks like the solution is migrating to EMM to do what was possible before using only admin apps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).